# HFS external drive aways mount read-only

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

I am having a problem with an external HFS+ USB drive on a MacBook Pro running High Sierra:

When I plug the drive into the computer, it gets automatically mounted as `read-only`. I have to manually remount it to make it `read-write`:

`sudo mount -u -w -v /Volumes/hdd`

However, if I plug the same drive into my older MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion, the drive is mounted `read-write` as expected.

I have erased (formatted) the disk many times over, and also tried `diskutil verifyDisk` and `diskutil verifyVolume`, everything seems clean.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot / fix this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: The machine was being managed remotely and the admin team started enforcing `read-only` access to remote USB devices